# Custom analyzer in lucene which will accept special chars

Tags: java, lucene

I'm a newbie to lucene indexing in java, I want to write the custom analyzer which will accept the below string without removing any special chars.

Currently Im using StandardAnalyzer in lucene. Problem comes when I'm trying to pass "**Refrigerator & A/C**" --> Standard analyzer is removing the special characters and storing the above mentioned string like this "**refrigerator a c**".

To get rid of this situation, I want to write the customAnalyzer in lucene(java). I don't to use any whitespaceanalyzer or some other thing. Can you pour your suggestions